# secure random seed and derby database creation

Tags: encryption, derby, bouncycastle, random-seed, secure-random

this my encrypted DB:

private static final String EMBEDDEDDRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
"jdbc:derby:./db;create=true;dataEncryption=true;bootPassword=somepassword;encryptionProvider=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;encryptionAlgorithim=AESEngine/CFBBlockCipher/NoPadding;sqlAutorization=true";

I extended the JCE jars to my jdk security and made provider priority as follows:
security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
security.provider.2=sun.security.provider.Sun

when I tried to create the db...I get this exception :

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng.SP800SecureRandom.setSeed(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$Default.engineSetSeed(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.setSeed(SecureRandom.java:427)

I'm just trying create a DB.. what the seeds has to do at this stage (pardon me as I'm very fresh with encryption )
if there is answer of same question I hope you direct me to OR get me an answer ...both ways appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Well.. Reversing the providers priority solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in weblogic and I solved it by copying the Providers BouncyCastle JARS files (both of them: `bcprov-jdk15on-159.jar` and `bcprov-ext-jdk15on-159.jar`) in `lib/ext` folder of the JRE. 
When I got the error, I had copied just `bcprov-jdk15on-159.jar` and not the other.